# GPS tracker than can send locations to TCP server

Tags: gps-tracking

Is there any simple GPS application in Android Market that can

1. Run in background
2. Send locations via GSM-Sim / GPS, time to a TCP Server:Port
3. TCP Server:Port is customizable so that I can set it to my server.
4. Send location after some n seconds (n is customizable)

That's the minimum requirement. If the application can also send battery status that more better.

Comment: This really isn't a good question for this site. You can search the Market just as easily as any of us. What apps have you already tried? What problem are you trying to solve? (Please read the [FAQ].)

Answer (score 1):

Not a definite answer but an idea. You can also try automation applications like Tasker and write a small sequence that will periodically report the gps location.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [myGPS4u](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.software4u.mygps4u). Exactly what you are looking for.